# Remove black SVG fill in C3.js time-series chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, c3.js

I'm trying to create a time-series chart using C3.js following [this example](https://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html), but generated chart creates black `svg` fill which isn't exactly what I want. How can I set `fill` property to `none`? See code at [`stackblitz.com`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xtqa3c).

```js
import * as c3 from 'c3';

const appDiv = document.getElementById('#app');
c3.generate({
  bindto: appDiv,
  data: {
    x: 'x',
    columns: [
      ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-06'],
      ['data', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350]
    ]
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries',
      tick: {
        format: '%Y-%m-%d'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c3) you are using as a dependency in your stackblitz code sample is omitting the **c3 css style**. If you reference the [c3 github link](https://github.com/c3js/c3), there is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kYJu/4742/) given there to fork when trying it out, which references both the c3.js and the c3.css (which sets the `fill` to none)

Here is a [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/t0a4rwqn/) with your code, showing a non-filled timeseries

Hope this helps.